# recaptcha The remote name could not be resolved: 'api-verify.recaptcha.net'

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I am using the ASP.net recaptcha control with .net 2.0 and c#. I have 
copied the example packaged with the .net demo.

Intermitently, when submitting the recaptcha I am getting the error 
"The remote name could not be resolved: 'api-verify.recaptcha.net'". 
Othertimes, everything works happily.

I have been assured that our firewall isn't blocking it (will explore that avenue further on Monday!). Just wanted to check has anyone else experienced this / have any suggestions?!

Comment: some recaptcha firewall information here.  http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/Firewalls_and_reCAPTCHA   
but if you're firewall was blocking it I'd expect to see it happening consistently.    

don't suppose you're in a load balanced scenario and one of your servers is having trouble accessing the address?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a network problem (too slow or too crowded sometimes)